# Unrestricted movement of lines Alt-Up/Down

Tags: org-mode, text-editing, lines

I'm learning Orgmode and moving lines (headers, checkbox items) up and down.
These movement are restrited to a tree part of the line (header section, checkbox list):

```
* Here is a list
 - Item 1
 - Item 2
 - Item 3 - Alt-down stops here

* Another list 
 - Here is where I want to move the line Item 3
```

Is there a simple way to move line without restriction in orgmode?

The closest I learned is C-k on a line -> move cursor -> C-y on other line.

Ideally is htere some modifier like Alt-Shift-Arrow?

Answer (score 1):

Name and documentation of this function says it all:

```
Signature
(org-shiftmetaup &optional ARG)

Documentation
Drag the line at point up.

In a table, kill the current row.
On a clock timestamp, update the value of the timestamp like S-<up>
but also adjust the previous clocked item in the clock history.
Everywhere else, drag the line at point up.
```

The name says that this function is bound to `S-M-<up>`.

You can look up the documentation of any function with `M-x describe-function` which is bound to `C-h f`.

Comment: Do you have a link to that part of docs? Googling did not help. Also does not say much to a new user unfortunately: is there another key binding other than Alt-arrow? How is it invoked? Why is it dragging a line in one curcumstrance and killing a row in another? How to use it?